# What does this.setState() call do in reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I basically know what `this.setState()` is for but I'm wondering what the call of that construct is doing. There is an example within the documentations of reactjs which shows *setState* in action but I'm confused about the construct.

Here:

```
handleClick() {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleOn: !prevState.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
```

Here is the full example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/xEmzGg?editors=0010)

In my understanding the *setState*-function is called. As an argument there is arrow-function. **But where does *prevState* came from?**

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate

Comment: It might make more sense if you write `this.setState(function (previousState) { return { isToggleOn: !previousState.isToggleOn }; })`. You can name the argument of the function whatever you see fit.

Comment: Yeah, that's a good complement. But I'm wondering where the value for previousState is going to come from. See my comment under @Quentin's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`prevState` is the name of an argument.

As with all arguments, their value is determined when the function is called, by the code which calls the function.

You are passing the function as an argument to `setState`.

You haven't included the source code to `setState` there, but it will be somewhere in or beyond that.

i.e. written by someone else.

You probably don't need to see that code. The documentation for `setState` should tell you what arguments will be passed to the callback function.

Comment: Yeah but the question for me is: When Im passing the function as an argument, who is "providing""/filling" the argument of the function itself. As far I understand, I'm passing a function definition which will be called before(!) setState is called to substitute the return value as the effective argument which is than gonna handle over as the real argument, so setState is going to get called with an Object-Literal as the argument right? So again: Where does the VALUE for prevState came from?

Comment: "When Im passing the function as an argument, who is "providing""/filling" the argument of the function itself." — I stated that quite clearly: You haven't included the source code to setState there, but it will be somewhere in or beyond that.

Comment: "As far I understand, I'm passing a function definition which will be called before(!) setState is called" — No. I explained that too: "You are passing the function as an argument to setState.". You are passing the *function*. You are not calling the function and passing its return value.

Comment: "setState is going to get called with an Object-Literal as the argument right?" – Wrong. "You are passing **the function** as an argument to setState."

Comment: AH! Now I see. That was the point. Since I came from Java, passing a whole function instead of its return value to another function is still unexpected. Thanks for that! :)